# How I Set Property of Element In InnerHtml

Tags: javascript

I want to add a `src` attribute to an `img` element inside the `PicsCircleMan`.

This solution is not working:

```
  (document.getElementsByTagName('img').PicsCircleMan.innerHTML).src =picsListMan[indexMan].img;
```

The `src` attribute is not assigned to the `<img>` element.

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: What exactly does your element look like?

Comment: Can you show your HTML. I think `.PicsCircleMan` might be undefined.

Comment: What does it mean "inside the PicsCircleMan"

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `document.getElementsByTagName('img').src = picsListMan[indexMan].img;` -

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('img').` returns an HTML collection. Have no clue what you are trying to do with that random property at the end.

Comment: yes......................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(document.getElementsByTagName('img').PicsCircleMan.innerHTML).src =picsListMan[indexMan].img;`

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a nodeList (array-like object) of all elements with the provided tag name. You can then access them with [i] where i is an array index. `.PicsCircleMan` means absolutely nothing there.

`.innerHTML` returns a string of the html code found inside an element.

`.src` is an attribute of `img` elements, but you're trying to set a `src` attribute on the `innerHTML` string, which doesn't mean anything.

You probably wanted to do someting like:
`document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "something.jpg";`